# Unable to get reddit mobile referrer

Tags: javascript, php

In order to make a special greeting to my reddit incoming traffic I would like to be able to know when the traffic is coming from there.

Adding a ref variable in the url is not a option as I don't have control of the url being posted.

I use **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']**. It works for reddit desktop traffic. However I get a blank http_referer when it comes to reddit mobile / app traffic.

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(strpos($ref, 'reddit') !== false){
  echo 'hello redditor';
}
```

I tried with javascript but it doesn't show anything as well.

```
var ref = document.referrer;
alert(ref);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this will works *only* if the reddit app / browser mobile send the referer with the http headers. If the reddit app uses a recognizable UserAgent you can that.